# Display Screen Brightness after running blank command

Tags: linux, framebuffer, lcd

I was looking into one of my board's code and found that the brightness of the Display reduces if I execute the following command

```
echo "0" > /sys/class/graphics/fb1/blank
```

This is put in the init script and executed on start.

After the board boots up, if I execute the following command, the brightness comes back to full intensity.

```
echo "1" > /sys/class/graphics/fb1/blank
```

What is the significance of this command or relation with screen brightness.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between `/sys/class/graphics/fbX/blank` (blank/unblank display) and screen brightness. (other than blanking an unblanking the display) Turn the lights off and look at the display, it will still be powered but black (blanked). Backlight control is a separate implementation, generally through `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` or via your desktop through `xrandr Backlight` or other desktop utilities. Backlight controls power and brightness controls just that, pixel brightness. When your display goes to sleep through your screen saver (ACPI/APM) if you do the same lights-out test, your display will be unpowered (no dim glow of a black screen).

There is a significant distinction between backlight control (display power) and display brightness (pixel brightness) that you need to be aware of from a power consumption standpoint (the latter allowing a dimming of pixels to give the impression of backlight control, but does not affect display power consumption -- not what you want when looking to preserve laptop battery power).

Both are accessible through `xrandr` and are unfortunately used in an intermixed way. For example, the `/sys/class/backlight/.../brightness` is a measure of the `backlight` and does affect display power even though the word `brightness` is used. Conversely in `xrandr` `Brightness` means brightness and dims pixels but does not change display power.

If you are looking to change the display backlight, then look at `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/...` or for some proprietary drives, a specific kernel module may be exposed, e.g. `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/...`. Check the `max_brightness` value to determine the acceptable range of values for your hardware (they can be `0-8`, `0-100`, etc..) Use this backlight control to set display appearance as it does reduce display power.

Otherwise, look at `xrandr`, e.g. for your laptop display `xrandr --output LVDS-0 --set Backlight 50` always check `xrandr --verbose` for the allowable range of backlight. `--set Backlight 50` also properly reduces display power, while changing the `Brightness` setting in `xrandr` does not!

Hopefully this has answered your question -- as it was a bit open-ended. If not, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have an ARM Based board running Embedded Linux which does not have acpi feature.

Comment: Well, that would make things more interesting. I don't have any other specifics for ARM boards (other than to be able to say, it will be different) Which board? Raspberry? Something else? There is good documentation on the web about the Raspberry interface. Other ARM board would probably have similar board specific interface information.

Comment: Freescale board: imx6

Comment: It looks like you are right "The LVDS connector is following the JILI30 standard and does just have display signals. There ar no signals and/or power for the backlight." [backlight control for LVDS](http://forum.fs-net.de/index.php/Thread/3949-backlight-control-for-LVDS/) See contra: [How to change the backlight level ?](https://community.nxp.com/thread/466446)

Comment: Exactly, it's LVDS Display. Brightness is 100% until the command is executed. The problem is I don't have another display connected. So, why blanking fb1 is affecting the brightness of fb0